# How to handle 3rd Party Dependencies while Unit Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am developing a plugin for a proprietary application.

The specification essentially is that I have functions with specified names.  When installed, the parent application will call the functions in my plugin - passing in various parameters.

I want to unit test my plugin, but I don't have access to the source of the parent application.  I can't instantiate the required parameters to test my function.

In this particular case, my parameter is an object with two data elements I access and a logging function that I access.  Mocking up a sample wouldn't be too difficult, but I'm faced with a bit of a dilemma...

```
public PerSpecResponseObject myPluginFunction(ThirdPartyObject iUseThis){
...
}
```

I can't pass my own object into "myPluginFunction", I need something of the type ThirdPartyObject.  If I define an interface, I don't have access to the ThirdPartyObject to specify that it implements the interface.  I can't subclass ThirdPartyObject and use a generic parameter (`<? extends ThirdPartyObject>`), because my plugin is implementing an interface, so my parameter types are restricted. I looked into Mocking and while interesting, it didn't seem applicable for my situation.

What solutions exist for this situation?

Comment: Mocking frameworks should let you mock out ThirdPartyObject and control what values get returned from its method calls. Why doesn't it seem applicable?

Comment: @EricStein - several resources I referenced strongly recommended against mocking 3rd party libraries.  Of course, none of them are showing up in my search results now...

Comment: @TurtlePowered  You would not be mocking a 3rd party library.  You would be mocking your **client**.  That's not a 3rd party library.  That's a 2nd party library, of not a 1st party library!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would indeed be best to be able to construct a real `ThirdPartyObject`.

Since you need to refer to this class, you have at least some 3rd party library on your class path that contains this class.
Are you sure there's no way to construct it, e.g. using a factory which is also in the library?  Or by constructing another object and calling a method that will call your plugin with a `ThirdPartyObject` instance?

While this is *sometimes* called integration testing (since you're testing the integration with the main application), it can also be considured unit testing in the classical sense as long as the test doesn't e.g. put data in a database or does anything else that could potentially influence other tests.

**If the above isn't possible**, you may resort to mocking out `ThirdPartyObject` e.g. using *Mockito*.  Try to make sure you your test code isn't coupled to your implementation any more than it needs to be.  Some people think they need to mock out all dependencies of a class and then verify all method calls to those dependencies.  They're introducing a lot of strong coupling and redundancy.

Concerning the 2 problems you mentioned, there are ways around both:

1) You say you can't make `ThirdPartyObject` implement an interface.  That's true, but you can write an adapter that implements this interface and delegates to a `ThirdPartyObject`.  Then the method called by the main application would simply delegate to the actual plugin method implementation that uses this interface.

Example (suppose `ThirdPartyObject` has a single method `void thirdPartyMethodCall()`:

```
public interface InterfaceForThirdPartyObject {
    void thirdPartyMethodCall();
}

public class ThirdPartyObjectAdapter implements InterfaceForThirdPartyObject {
    private final ThirdPartyObject delegate;

    public ThirdPartyObjectAdapter(ThirdPartyObject delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void thirdPartyMethodCall() {
        delegate.thirdPartyMethodCall();
    }
}

// your actual plugin implementation, not directly exposed to the main app
public class MyPlugin {
    public PerSpecResponseObject myPluginFunction(InterfaceForThirdPartyObject iUseThis){
        // this will contain your actual logic that you want to test
    }
}

// this is the plugin as exposed to the main app
public class MyPluginAdapter implements PluginInterface {
    private final MyPlugin delegate = new MyPlugin();

    // this is called by the main application
    public PerSpecResponseObject myPluginFunction(ThirdPartyObject iUseThis) {
        delegate.myPluginFunction(new ThirdPartyObjectAdapter(iUseThis));
    }
}
```

2) You say you can't subclass `ThirdPartyObject` because the plugin implements an interface that has a `ThirdPartyObject` as method argument instead of `? extends ThirdPartyObject`.  I don't see why that would be a problem: a method that takes a `ThirdPartyObject` as parameter will happily take instances of any subclass of `ThirdPartyObject`.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around option 1 because I think that would be quite useful in a lot of situations.  You don't happen to have a code sample that you can point me to, do you?

Comment: Added quick'n'dirty example, probably doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

If you had access to the source of the parent application, you wouldn't be unit-testing, but integration-testing.

You can mock `ThirdPartyObject`.  In fact, you **have to** mock `ThirdPartyObject` if what you want to do is unit-testing.

Just create a class with the same FQN as `ThirdPartyObject`, but keep it in your test folders so it doesn't get distributed.

This is the simplest I can think of.

Comment: The above statement is not necessarily true: for the same reason you don't need to mock e.g. Guava just because it's a 3rd party library.  If simply instantiating and initializing ThirdPartyObject was possible, it would most likely be the way to go, at least if it wouldn't mean the test had side effects that could potentially influence other tests (if it had, it would indeed be an integration test).